# Совмещение изображения с его названием

Tags: jquery

```
var forum_icon = $(this).find('.forumIcoTd img').map(function() { return $(this).attr('src'); }).get().join('');

var forum_fname = $(this).find('.forum').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join('');

alert(forum_icon); - /f1.png /f2.png /f3.png /f4.png
alert(forum_fname) - Форум 1 Форум 2 Форум 3 Форум 4
```

А хотелось бы так: /f1.png Форум1 f2.png Форум2 и т.д..

На данном этапе выдаёт сначала весь список `forum_icon`, а потом `forum_fname`. А как сделать, чтобы выдавал например сначала первый элемент из `forum_icon`, а потом из `forum_fname`. И так далее.

Comment: Уже не первая тема создается с сомнительными вопросами. Может все-таки покажите структуру html и чего вы пытаетесь добиться? Очень сложно отвечать на вопрос, не представляя себе картины и не до конца понимая какой результат на выходе пытается получить человек.

Comment: Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учитывайте размеры массивов и какой используете в цикле **if**, в счетчике!

```
var forum_icon = $(this).find('.forumIcoTd img')
    .map(function() { 
        return $(this).attr('src'); 
    }).get();

var forum_fname = $(this).find('.forum')
    .map(function() { 
        return $(this).text(); 
    }).get();

var i = 0;
var groupEl = [];
for(i; i < forum_icon.length; i++) {
    groupEl.push(forum_icon[i],forum_fname[i]);
}
alert(groupEl);
```

P.S. Обратите внимание на то, что после метода **.map()** не используем **.join('')**. Это можно сделать, если надо, уже с общим массивом: **groupEl.join('');**

Comment: var i = 0;
  var groupEl = [];
  for(i; i < forum_icon.length; i++) {
    var f_icon = forum_icon[i];
    var f_name = forum_fname[i];
    var f_tmpl = ''+f_icon+' : '+f_name+'';
    groupEl.push(f_tmpl);
  }
  $('#new_forum').html(groupEl);

Почему так не работает?

Comment: Потому, что функция **push** добавляет значения в конец массива, а вы, как я понял, хотите одно значение использовать как ключ. Или я не так понял?

P.S. Вам уже дал тонкий намёк @iKuzko по поводу того, что хорошо бы определить задачи.

Comment: Мне просто вывести результат не в alert'e, а в div с id="new_forum"

Comment: Вы до конца мой ответ дочитали?

    $('#new_forum').html(groupEl.join(','));

Comment: Подойдите к решению задачи с другой стороны.

Вы собираете сначала два массива (для картинок и для названий форума)затем эти массивы объединяете в строки и дальше мучаетесь пытаясь вывести данные в нужном порядке (объединяя 2 строки).

Вместо этого соберите сразу данные по картинкам и названиям форума в правильный массив и затем только объединяйте в строку ( если нужно ) и выводите в div.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы гений!

Comment: Можно приблизительный код?

Comment: @Руслан Дуров, вот вы интересный )) А я разве не показал вам "приблизительный код"? Может у вас какой-то тайный замысел? Так посветите в него, иначе я уже не понимаю, что вам надо.

Comment: Извините, кто мне сможет помочь по jQuery?